# Drive account associated with Appengine Service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, drive

I recently noticed that there is a drive account related to me Appengine's Service account where I can push/read files using python code on Appengine using my service account as a user.
My questions are:

1.) Is the drive account available by default as 1 per GCP application or 1 per Service account (as I can create multiple service account)?

2.) What is the quota on the Drive account available in this case?

3.) How can I access the drive account associated with service account from web UI (as we do with user account)?

4.) Can you provide any additional information on how this drive is similar/different from the general drive accounts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experimenting a little with this API.

1) The drive account is global to the project

2) It's not clear whether there is a quota, but it looks like a regular user, so you should expect the same limit as for your business accounts

3) You can't. What I do is give Edit access to a folder I own to the account so that it can generate new files and update existing ones.

4) It looks like a regular user, but it's intended to be used by machines, there is no way to set a password AFAIK.

However, I must warn you that there is currently a problem when trying to access the Drive API with those service accounts because they don't support scoping, needed for Drive API.

[Insufficient Permission with Appengine Flex service account to access Drive folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144128/appengine-service-account-to-access-drive-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a drive account associated with every service account and its limit is same as a normal gmail user.

But, you can see drive content in a GUI like you can do in normal gmail user.

Comment: If you really want a UI, I would suggest, that instead of using  service account, create an admin account and do all upload and read operations from that account in your code.